# Regex to match 0 - 999 but not blank

Tags: regex

I'm working on a regex to match valid integer numbers such as the following:

- 0
- 1
- 99
- 999

However it should not allow matching an empty string.  The closest I can get is:

```
(0)|\\d{1,3}
```

Which to me says a matching string will have either a zero or a series of digits between 1 and 3 characters long.  However, empty strings still appear to match this pattern.  What's the proper way to exclude empty strings from this regex?

Comment: A zero is also a digit, `\\d{1,3}` should do fine. Why the double backslash, though?

Comment: (i) \d also includes 0, so the (0) part shouldn't be needed. (ii) an empty string shouldn't match this. What language/library/function are you using?

Comment: This `^\d{1,3}$` should work fine

Comment: @MvanGeest: In some languages, you have to escape all the escaping backslashes in a regex pattern string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will match (only) a series of one to three numeric digits (including 0 or 00 or 01 or 012 - not clear if those latter ones are desired):

```
^\d{1,3}$
```

It will not match empty string (but then neither will your original convoluted expression).

(To allow this as part of a bigger string, remove the `^` and `$` anchors.)

But perhaps regex is not best option here - does whatever base language you're using not have an isNumeric function?

To allow 0 but not other 0-prefixed numbers, you can use:

```
0|[1-9]\d{0,2}
```

Or, to ensure that's the entire match:

```
^(?:0|[1-9]\d{0,2})$
```

Comment: your regex will mach such as **001, 002**

Comment: Yes, and I explicitly stated this in my answer.  It's not clear in the question if that's undesired, but I've added an expression that will exclude those.

Comment: @Yousui: Leading zeroes should be automatically dropped when a string consisting of an integer is cast to an integer type, so unless James Cadd is using the integers captured by the regex within an `eval()` statement of some sort then leading zeroes are fine.

Comment: Thanks, this looks correct.  I think my problem with the empty string is related to the way the control suite I'm using interprets regexes.

Comment: @James - This is just a wild guess but if by chance you're using ASP.NET validators, the default behavior of a RegexValidator is to NOT even evaluate the value if it's blank.  So to take care of this you have to include a RequiredFieldValidator in addition to the RegexValidator.  The same basic principle is true of Peter Blum's validation controls, and is probably common to other control suites as well.

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
^[1-9][0-9]{1,2}$|^\d$
```

This will match:

```
0
1
99
999
```

But will not match:

```
01
001
1234
```

Comment: Upvoted this because this is exactly what I needed (not sure if it's what the OP wanted though).

Answer (score 1):

> (0)|\d{1,3}

What is the purpose of `(0)|`? `\d` is any digit, and 0 is a digit. `\\d{1,3}` should do just fine. Or do you not want leading zeroes?

Anyway, it's either a problem with the regex engine of whatever you're using, and/or you're doing an unnecessary escape on `\d` there. Perhaps the regex engine doesn't support the `{min, max}` syntax?

EDIT: For those giving examples matching the start and end of strings: why are you making the assumption that the strings being checked will only contain one of the integers being checked for?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple pattern you can use **^(0|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2})$**

It accepts 
0 
1 
12 
123 
999

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-9]+$
```

should work: it says that there is a number, any one between 0 and 9 at least one time from the beginning to the end of the string.

Test with grep -E : empty lines prints nothing, space prints nothing, but 9 or 99 prints 9 or 99.

Other test with perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my @str = ('', ' ', '9', '99', '123');

foreach (@str) {
    print "$_ -> ";
    if (/^[0-9]+$/) {
    print "match\n";
    }
    else {
    print "not match\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: your regex will mach such as **001, 002**

Comment: of course, this will also match 1234 and the original question seems to require only matching up to three digits.

Comment: When I first answer, there was no precision about the size of the stuff to be matched. Moreover, the most important idea in my post is the ^ and $.