# Regex to allow values 1 to 100 with some conditions

Tags: c#, regex

i want a regex to allow 1-3 digits whole number,it should not start with 0 and should be a whole number,not decimals or fractions or any signed values,

this is what i have tried

```
"/^(\s*|\d{1,3})$/"
```

but it does not seem to work..

thanks in advance

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071162/regex-to-match-0-999-but-not-blank

Comment: remove enclosing slashes. They are required just for JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
^(([1-9]\d?)|100)$
```

This would ensure that

- There is at least one digit
- That multi-digit numbers start in a digit other than zero
- That the only allowed three-digit number is 100.

Comment: You need to group the alternation, this way the anchors belong to the alternatives ==> `^[1-9]\d?` or `100$`, [regexr](http://regexr.com?350p9)

Comment: @Nolonar You are right, a pair of parentheses was missing. Thanks!

Comment: The original question was any one to three digit number, not just 100 as a three digit number.

Comment: @unxnut The title of the question somewhat contradicts the body, but it asks for "values 1 to 100", hence the regex.

Comment: I don't know, why you capture the first alternative, but otherwise this regex should now be correct. +1

Comment: sorry,if my question contradicts..it should be max three digit, min of one digit..but not 0 and not more than 100,and only numbers and no decimals..thanks for the answer..i will try and see if it satisfies all the condition..thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

```
^[1-9][0-9]\{,2\}$
```

It should be indeed end of line; end-of word will get the fractional part.

Comment: The `\{` and `\]` should be replaced with `{` and `}`. Why would you want to escape them ?

Comment: This allows any number between 1 and 199, not 1 and 100.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: It allows any number between 1 and 999.  I had read the description that said 1-3 digit whole number.  You should get your facts right before downvoting.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. Did you not read the title of the question?

Comment: Yes, and as dasblinkenlight pointed in his comment, the title and body are a bit contradictory.  Anyway, I do not want to argue with a u$ person.  I won't post any more on this.