# RegEx allowing digit, dash, comma

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to know the regular expression for c# fulfill the following pattern:

- only allow numbers, comma and digit
- must start and end with digit
- range of digit is 0 to 999
- digits (e.g. 1,2,3) or range (e.g. 1-3, 2-5) are separated by ','
- between two ',' must be a digit or range
- '-' must start and end with digit
- Allow only 0-1 white space after ','

**Example:**

```
1-100,134,200 --> PASS. Maximum range of numbers 0-999
1,18,100      --> PASS
1, 18, 100    --> PASS. Allow 0-1 white space after ',' 
1,  18,100    --> FAIL. Due to more than 1 white space after ','
1-,18,100     --> FAIL. Due to no digit after '-'
-2,18,100     --> FAIL. Due to no digit before '-'
1,,18,100     --> FAIL. Due to no digit between ','
1, ,18,100    --> FAIL. Due to no digit between ','
,2,18,100     --> FAIL. Due to no digit before ','
1,18,100,     --> FAIL. Due to no digit after ','
```

I tried using the following code but it always return a true result:

```
string pattern = @"[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?(,[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?)*";
string test = @"1-5,13,238,-a";
bool result = Regex.IsMatch(test, pattern);
```

Comment: When working with regex I always found rubular.com very usefull, check that, it will def. help you.

Comment: It works when I use regexr.com to validate the expression. However, when I use the c# code, it keeps returning "true". Beside this, I am also not sure how to limit the digits and add white space expression into it as I copied the expression from else where.

Comment: Something like this might work: `^(?:\d+(?:-\d+)?,?\s?)+$` (Edit: won't work  when there is a comma at the end)

Comment: @adiga your expression works for most of the cases except for the comma at the end (which you have pointed) and digit range (0 to 999). I can simply do a string check using c# codes to check for endswith comma. Can anyone know how to modify adiga's expression to support the range?

Comment: aah didn't see the 999 bit. Replace `\d` with `\d{1,3}`.

Comment: (Don't want to increase the complexity of the question, but is `100-50` a valid range?)

Comment: @adiga you bought up a good point. It would be nice to invalid the ranges like 100-50. but if it can't be done using regex, I can live with it.

Comment: Look into parsers. This would be much more clearly implemented by treating it as a context free grammar. Regex is not designed to evaluate such languages.

Comment: @jpmc Thanks for the suggestion. I don't expect regex to do condition checks. Currently, I am using other means do condition check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
^(?:[1-9]\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(?:-(?:[1-9]\d\d|[1-9]?\d))?(?:,\s?(?:[1-9]\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(?:-(?:[1-9]\d\d|[1-9]?\d))?)*$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?:[1-9]\d\d|[1-9]?\d)` - Represents a number `0` to `999` and does not allow numbers with leading zeroes like `005`
- `(?:-(?:[1-9]\d\d|[1-9]?\d))?` - Optionally also allows a number separated by hyphen `-` so together with first regex digit, it supports numbers like `22` and `22-33` etc
- `(?:,\s?(?:[1-9]\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(?:-(?:[1-9]\d\d|[1-9]?\d))?)*` - This part just supports comma separated optionally followed by a whitespace and whole of it zero or more times
- `$` - End of string

I could have used `\d{1,3}` to represent a number from `0` to `999` but this would allow numbers like `004` which doesn't seem to be allowed seeing your sample data. But if indeed it is okay to allow numbers like `004` or `04` then you can replace `[1-9]\d\d|[1-9]?\d` with `\d{1,3}` in my regex to make it simple.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gufpH4/1/)**

Comment: Thanks. You expression works. You even help me to eliminate the zeros in front.

Comment: @user1599647: Glad I could help and yes, writing a precise regex for a number `0` to `999` while not allowing leading zeroes is what I thought you required seeing your sample data in post, which is what made my regex a little complex but good to know you indeed wanted that.

Comment: ...... If I saw this in your code, I would be having a conversation with your supervisor. It would take anyone 20 minutes minimum to untangle that mess. This is not production ready. -1.

Comment: @jpmc26: Well, its same like, trying to read/understand a language that one doesn't know/understand. For anyone who knows regex basics, my regex should be trivial. Also, I've added the explanation to my regex which should make it easily understandable. And if you can come up with a simpler and more readable regex than mine, I'll consider you a true regex master and give you my hats off.

Comment: @jpmc26 The provided regex _does_ answer the question, though, and indeed contains an "untangling" which could easily be inserted into "production code" as a comment. That said... I've seen far more complicated regexes as a matter of course in production code. There's nothing wrong with it if properly tested and documented (and if the level of complexity can be justified relative to the problem being solved). +1 from me.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I know regex very well. The pattern is a still a nightmarish mess. You have 3 look arounds nested inside another look around. Looks like a high risk of run away backtracking to me. Why do you have so many look arounds anyway? I'm fairly certain this is a regular language; it shouldn't require any.

Comment: @jpmc26: Lookarounds? Where did you see that? I thought you said you know regex very well. Can you show what you see as lookarounds?

Comment: @TypeIA I didn't say it didn't answer the question. I said it's a *bad* answer.

Comment: Forgive me. I mistook the completely unnecessary non-capture groups for look around. Why have you needlessly complicated the pattern for a match test (which doesn't need to capture anything)? Also, I had to sit and figure out if your regex matched the empty string or not. It's *way* too complicated.

Comment: @jpmc26: Honestly speaking, I don't think you even understood my regex properly. Otherwise you should have been asking this question to other answers too, whose regex is same as mine except their regex allows leading zeroes in the digits as they have used `\d{1,3}` instead of `[1-9]\d\d|[1-9]?\d` else the structure is same. The reason why you didn't ask this same question to them tells me you don't know regex very well as you couldn't decode my regex. My regex if written in simpler form can be written as, `X(-X)?(,X(-X)?)*` where `X` = `[1-9]\d\d|[1-9]?\d`. Can you see how simple it is indeed?

Comment: I reject the premise. Regex is a poor solution to this problem. I already left a comment about the approach I recommend.

Comment: @jpmc26: Why regex is a poor solution to this problem? And even if it is, what about OP not having any other choice than to use a regex? Also, if you think coding would be a better solution, then I don't agree. If you know regex well enough, then this regex is nothing compared to what I have seen other regexes. Following your philosophy, people with good regex capabilities are useless and not needed because in case regex gets complex, they need to move to coding solution. Sorry but I don't agree with this.

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
   ^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\-[0-9]{1,3})?(?:,\s?[0-9]{1,3}(?:\-[0-9]{1,3})?)*$
```

pattern where

```
   ^                             String start
   0*[0-9]{1,3}                  1 to 3 digits
   (?:\-[0-9]{1,3})?             Possible minus (-) followed 1 to 3 digits (e.g. -456)
   ?:,\s?                        Comma and at most one whitespace  
   [0-9]{1,3}(?:\-[0-9]{1,3})?)* 1 to 3 digits or range repeated zero or more times
   $                             End of string
```

**Demo:**

```
  string pattern = 
    @"^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\-[0-9]{1,3})?(?:,\s?[0-9]{1,3}(?:\-[0-9]{1,3})?)*$";

  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "123",
    "1234",
    "123-456",
    "123,456",
    "1-100,134,200",
    "1,18,100",
    "1, 18, 100",
    "1,  18,100",
    "1-,18,100",
    "-2,18,100",
    "1,,18,100",
    "1, ,18,100",
    ",2,18,100",
    "1,18,100,",
  };

  string[] results = tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-20} --> {(Regex.IsMatch(test, pattern) ? "PASS" : "FAIL")}")
    .ToArray();

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, results);

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
123                  --> PASS
1234                 --> FAIL 
123-456              --> PASS
123,456              --> PASS
1-100,134,200        --> PASS
1,18,100             --> PASS
1, 18, 100           --> PASS
1,  18,100           --> FAIL
1-,18,100            --> FAIL
-2,18,100            --> FAIL
1,,18,100            --> FAIL
1, ,18,100           --> FAIL
,2,18,100            --> FAIL
1,18,100,            --> FAIL
```

**Edit:**

- If you want to allow arbitrary many leading zeros (e.g. `000123` which is in fact `123`), change each `[0-9]{1,3}` fragment into `0*[0-9]{1,3}`
- If you want ban leading zeroes (`012` must fail, when `12` or `0` must) pass, change each `[0-9]{1,3}` fragment into `(?:0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})`

Comment: You expression works. Unfortunately I can only check a post.as answer. Nonetheless, I upvote your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try following pattern: `^(?:\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}|\d{1,3})(?:, ?(?:\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}))*$`

Explanation:

`^` - match beginning of a string

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`\d{1,3}` - match between 1 and 3 digits

`-` - match dash literally

`|` - alternation, match what's on the right (`\d{1,3}`) or what on the left (`\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}`)

`, ?` - match `,` followed by zero or one space

`*` - match `(?:, ?(?:\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}))` zero or more times

`$` - match end of a string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4PyL4t/2)

Comment: You expression works. Unfortunately I can only check a post.as answer. Nonetheless, I upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt using `\b` a *word boundary*, maybe it's accurate enough for your needs.

```
^(?:\d{1,3}(?:-\d{1,3})?(?:, ?)?\b)+$
```

Play with it in [this demo at regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/8Vqeuh/4/) (explanation on the right side).

If you need the [0-999 check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071162/regex-to-match-0-999-but-not-blank) without leading zeros, replace [`\d{1,3}` with `(?:[1-9]\d\d?|\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/8Vqeuh/5)

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a lot of unusually complex answers here, so here's my 2 cents:

```
^([1-9]\d{0,2}|0)((\-|, ?)([1-9]\d{0,2}|0))*$
```

I consider this answer to be "less complex" not because its shorter (it's not the shortest here), but because it uses no "complex" regex behavior.
It uses only common matching groups `()`, common quantifiers (`*`, `{,}` and `?`) and common matching symbols such as `\d` and `[1-9]`

No lookarounds, lookaheads, lookbehinds, non-capturing groups, back-references, or any other "complex" regex behavior

### Explanation:

```
^([1-9]\d{0,2}|0)((\-|, ?)([1-9]\d{0,2}|0))*$
^                                               Start of string
 (                                              Start of capture group:
  [1-9]\d{0,2}                                    A non-zero digit followed by 0 to 2 digits.
                                                    Matches any 1-999 number without leading zeroes
              |                                   OR
               0                                  Just a zero
                )                               End of capture group
                 (                             Start of capture group:
                  (                              Start of capture group:
                   \-                              Dash
                     |                             OR
                      , ?                          Comma Followed by 1 or 0 spaces
                         )                       End of capture group
                          ([1-9]\d{0,2}|0)       Same 0-999 capture group as earlier
                                          )     End of capture group
                                           *    Previous capture group matched 0 or more times
                                            $   End of string
```

In short, in case you want a slightly less technical description:

`Number` is a number from 0-999
(Represented with the regex: `([1-9]\d{0,2}|0)`)

`Separator` is a comma plus 0 or 1 spaces, or a dash
(Represented with the regex: `(\-|, ?)`)

`Group` is a **Separator**, followed immediately by a **Number**
(Represented with the regex: `((\-|, ?)([1-9]\d{0,2}|0))`)

This regex matches:
A **Number** followed by zero or more **Groups**

#### Update

@bobblebubble in the comments pointed out that this will allow, for example `1-2-3`, which may not be allowed given `-` is intended to specify a range.

Here is a modification that fixes this:

```
^(([1-9]\d{0,2}|0)(-([1-9]\d{0,2}|0))?)(, ?(([1-9]\d{0,2}|0)(-([1-9]\d{0,2}|0))?))*$
```

This is much longer than the original, so in C# I would split it up as such:

```
// This pattern will match a single 0-999 number, or a range
string numPatt = "(([1-9]\d{0,2}|0)(-([1-9]\d{0,2}|0))?)";
// This pattern will match a csv of numPatts
string pattern = $"^{numPatt}(, ?{numPatt})*$";
```

Then use `pattern` as desired.

Comment: This is interesting, but it [matches eg `1-2-3`](https://regex101.com/r/QGEthJ/1) which I don't know if it is allowed (range). However good answer and explanation and an option as well!

Comment: @bobblebubble good point, not too difficult to update, will do so shortly