# I have a Input field it should allow values only from 0-999 , want a regex for that

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a Angular 7 Input ,I need a regex to allow values between 0-999 currently my code is like this my current pattern allows values between 0-31
  public endOfMonthDaysRegex: any = /^(0?[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/;

```
                         <input
                          type="number"
                          class="form-control"
                          ng-max="999"
                          ng-min="0"
                          name="dueDayOfMonth"
                          [(ngModel)]="dueDayOfMonth"
                          [required]="cpDueDayOfMonth"
                          [pattern]="endOfMonthDaysRegex"
                          [ngClass]="{
                            invalid:
                              form?.controls?.dueDayOfMonth?.errors?.required ||
                              (submitted && form?.controls?.dueDayOfMonth?.errors?.pattern)
                          }"`
                        />`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to match 0 - 999 but not blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071162/regex-to-match-0-999-but-not-blank)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex below will match `0`, `1`, ... `9`, `10`, `11` ... `99`, `100`, ... `999`.

It will NOT match zero-leading numbers (`01`, `024` etc.)

`/^(0|[1-9]\d{0,2})$/`

If you DO want to match zero-leading numbers, then simply:

`/^\d{1,3}$/`

Answer (score 2):

The following regular expression will match any digit 0-999

`/^(\d{1,3})$/`

Comment: You can also use the the site https://regex101.com/ to check and play with regex.